# Unable to delete custom object is used by another feature, but it's not

Tags: custom-object, delete

I am trying to delete a custom object. I receive the follow error:

This custom object is used by another feature. Remove the usage and try again.  Email Template

There are no references to this object in the email template. Any help?

Here is the object name: Copy_Record__c

Here is one VF email template that I am told references it:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Trip Approval Request" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Business_Trip__c">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody >


<table width="550px" border="0">

               <tr>

            <td>Trip Owner: {!relatedTo.Owner.name}</td>
<td>Trip Name: {!relatedTo.Name}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Trip Start: <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Start_Date__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText></td>
<td> End Date: <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.End_Date__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Number of Trips: {!relatedTo.NUmber_of_Meetings__c}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description: {!relatedTo.Description__c}</td>

</tr>
</table>
https://na12.salesforce.com/{!relatedTo.Id}
<p><b>Planned Meetings:</b></p>
<table border="1" >

    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Meetings__r}">
        <tr>
             <td>Name: {!cx.Who.name}</td>
             <td>Date: <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!cx.activityDate}" /> 
</apex:outputText></td>
             <td>Company: {!cx.What.name}</td>
             <td>Subject: {!cx.Subject}</td>
             <td>Notes Summary: {!cx.Comments_Summary__c}</td>
        </tr>

    </apex:repeat>                 
</table>
<p />



<p><b>Approval History:</b></p>
<table border="1" >

    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.ProcessSteps}">
        <tr>
             <td>Assigned to: {!cx.OriginalActor.name}</td>
             <td>Actual Approver: {!cx.Actor.name}</td>


            <td>Step Status: {!cx.StepStatus}</td>
            <td>Approvals Completed:{!cx.ProcessInstance.CompletedDate}</td>
            <td>Process:{!cx.ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.name}</td>



          <td>Comments:{!cx.Comments}</td>
        </tr>

    </apex:repeat>                 
</table>
<p />







</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Did you look in VF Email templates  -- the `relatedToType="mycustomObject__c"` attribute?  If you go to Eclipse and include Email in your project, you can quickly find this with email search if you have many templates to look through

Comment: It's not the related to type. It's not been used for anything.

Comment: (1) `Business_Trip__c.meetings__r` (a related list) by any chance refer to `Copy_record__c` ?  (2) How are `copy_record__c` and `Business_trip__c` related in the schema?

Comment: Not related in the schema. Copy_record__c has no look up fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried "editing" and re-saving the templates based on reading this question:
[Cannot delete, no references but still says referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3314/cannot-delete-no-references-but-still-says-referenced-elsewhere-in-salesforce-c)
It worked. 
I don't understand it all though.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try one of the numerous free Apps from the App Exchange to search the metadata like [Octopus](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5cEKEAZ) or [Schema Surfer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZM3EAM) to locate the template (or anything else) that's causing the issue you're having.

Comment: I will add example in the question.

Comment: Without seeing your schema, from the looks of it, I don't think your code is going to help. There's likely going to be a link of some kind, such as that template being available for use with that object that's likely the cause. From the object name, it almost sounds as though it perhaps holds a copy of a record that the template might use, thus creating an implicit link, but again, I wouldn't have any means of knowing. You're going to need to do a metadata search. In particular, check to see if it's enabled for events/activities which would seem to apply to that template.

Comment: How would I find an implicit reference? The object is not enabled for activities.

Comment: If the object wasn't enabled for activities, the above template wouldn't seem to apply unless the object is referenced by another object that it does apply to. Have you installed either of the apps?

Comment: Schema Surfer is not showing the custom objects I want to investigate. Is this a know limitation - it won't see a managed package obj?

Comment: It would depend on the App as to whether or not they can explore other namespaces. Managed packages are in a different namespace and most of their objects usually aren't visible to an org. It's been a while since I've used that one so can't tell you it's limitations. You can also try using Workbench as well where you can explore metadata yourself (you'll see managed packages listed). If it was an sObject or field, you could use the Schema ChildRelationshipClass even if in a managed package. There are Chrome plug-ins now that can also explore metadata.